# Why is my inner for loop producing more values than required? (Tried debugging but code is too short for any meaningful output)

Tags: python, loops

I am writing code to solve the following question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/solution/

Here is my brute force solution:

```
def subarraySum(nums, k: int) -> int:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):

        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if sum(nums[i:j]) == k:

                count += 1
                break
    return count

print(subarraySum([1,1,1],2))
```

The output of the above is 1, however when I run it on paper it should be 2! (and 2 is clearly the right answer) I have tried debugging the code, but it exits too soon for anything meaningful to be produced.

I have also tried debugging with print, and for `inner loop`, for some reason `j takes on 1,2,2` ; when it should only be `1,2`.

Any ideas where the code is falling short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `i` and `j` in the inner loop you will see the following output:

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
```

These are the start and end indexes for the ranges you want to sum. However, when you do

```
sum(nums[i:j])
```

it doesn't include the item at the end index in the sum. What you need to do is

```
sum(nums[i:j+1])
```

This gives the correct output of `2`.

Comment: Thanks Kemp, out of interest, there was no way of me 'seeing' this in the debugger correct? As I can't think of how I would have spotted this even alongside the debugger, but now that you point it out it seems obvious

Comment: The main clue really would be watching the values of `i` and `j` combined with knowing how the slicing works (i.e. not including the end index). When it comes down to checking the values or types of things I generally just print them rather than step through in the debugger (as long as it's not hundreds of iterations or something), but either would work.